# Accessing,filling and submitting a form using the URL it resides on from another form using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  have a blog (Blogger). I want to make a contact form. I made it using google forms. However the theme is not matching with my blog. Also I cannot customize that form. so what i thought is to build my own form. So when a user fills and submits the form i shall fill the google form (that has got a url) with the same and submit.

So my question is: Is it possible to access, fill and submit one form through its URL from another form using javascript or jquery. I know that we can fill a form or access elements of a form using javascript and also submit it FROM THE SAME FORM. But here the requirement is like Form A will be filled and submitted that will trigger a javascript function which using the URL, of say Form B, fill that form and hit the submit button of that form.

Kindly provide the solution.
Thanks and Regards.
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Instead you could replicate this form and see where it submits to etc. Another option would be fetching the form html and adding it to your page with custom styles.